# How do I install Lexmark P6350?

Tags: printing, lexmark

I'm really new to Ubuntu and not a programmer.

I am having problems getting my printer to work.  Ubuntu will detect it, but the test page fails to print.  If someone could provide a step by step guide that would be fantastic. I don't know what cups is.

Thanks a lot,

James.

Comment: Sorry that one is a paperweight for Linux. Lexmark does not provide support for it (it does for their X-series).

Answer (score 1):

[Lexmark never had support for the P6350](http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=content&productCode=&segment=SUPPORT&userlocale=EN_UK&id=RE108). Nothing changed since 2008.